# I am looking for alternative to Non Breaking space in HTML

Tags: html, css

In my HTML code whenever I use sentence like below :

```
<p> This is a example sentence </p> or
 <h3> This is header Sentence </h3>
```

It is displaying from extreme left side but I want some space before my sentence starts. For this I am using non breaking space. But it looks very ugly since I need to use 5 to 10 times of non breaking space like this :

```
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

I tried to use `&emsp;` also but in this case also i need to use 5 times. So what other options i have to make my sentence to start with some spaces??

Comment: You need to look into CSS margin/padding.

Comment: CSS margins or positioning ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `text-indent` property to indent your text inside a `p` or `h3`

Alternatively, if you are looking to pad up entire paragraph or header, you should have a wrapper `div` and use `padding` or `margin` for `p` as well as `h3`.

But as you said you are using `&nbsp;` am sure what you are looking for is `text-indent`.

```
p.class_name {
   text-indent: 20px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kKLA3/)

---

I've edited your question though, as you only used html tag, I have also added a CSS tag, but if you want a HTML solution than take a look at `pre` tag

Comment: Man you gave me so many options now i am confused which one to use. Haha anyways my problem solved and I am using inline style for time being. If i want to use this frequently then i will make a CSS class and will refer to that.

Comment: @Raj not necessary to refer a class, say you want to indent all the paragraphs which are nested inside a single element, you can simply use `div.class_name p {text-indent: 20px;}` this will indent each paragraph inside the `div` element having class `class_name` http://jsfiddle.net/kKLA3/1/ and I upvoted your question so you will get more features to use on Stackoverflow, enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding for

tag by using css like

```
p{
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using margins?

To always indent, use code such as this:

HTML

```
<p> This is a example sentence </p>
```

CSS

```
p{
   margin-left:10px;
}
```